# Bug with Bresenham's Line Drawing algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics

I'm trying to use [Bresenham's Line Drawing Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to draw a line on a 20x20 grid of tiles.

So basically, when the variable deltaerror (from the wiki) is greater than 1 (when the change in y is greater than the change in x), the y value becomes almost double what it should be. Hopefully, I explain it better in the comments of the code. I also think I found the source of the error, which I'll also explain in the comments.

This is the code I made, mostly copied from the pseudocode in the wiki.

```
public static void drawLine(Tile t1, Tile t2) {
    int dx = t2.x_index - t1.x_index;
    int dy = t2.y_index - t1.y_index;
    double error = 0;
    double d_error = Math.abs((double) dy / dx); // dx =/= 0, therefore no vertical lines

    // when d_error is greater than 1, the bug occurs

    int y = t1.y_index;
    if (d_error <= 1) { // if related acute angle is < 45 degrees
        if (dx < 0) { // line drawn towards left side of screen
            for (int x=t1.x_index; x>=t2.x_index; x--) {
                Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                error += d_error;
                while (error >= 0.5) {
                    Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                    y += dy > 0 ? +1 : -1;// this is where I think the error occurs. In the 
                                          // wiki for the algorithm, this should be some 
                                          // function sign(T) which "decides whether t is 
                                          // positive or negative". I wasn't really sure 
                                          // what this meant, so I just assumed it returned 
                                          // -1 if it was negative and +1 if it was positive. 
                                          // Also it's the only place where y is edited
                                          // that seems to be where the error is occurring. 
                    error -= 1.0;
                }
            }
        } else if (dx > 0) { // line drawn towards right side of screen
            for (int x=t1.x_index; x<=t2.x_index; x++) {
                Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                error += d_error;
                while (error >= 0.5) {
                    Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                    y += dy > 0 ? +1 : -1;
                    error -= 1.0;
                }
            }
        }

    // update: switched x and y values when d_error is greater than 1.

    } else { // if related acute angle is > 45 degrees
        dx = t2.y_index - t1.y_index; // switch x and y values
        dy = t2.x_index - t1.x_index;

        d_error = Math.abs((double) dy / dx); // recalculate d_error
        y = t1.x_index;
        if (dx < 0) { // line drawn towards left side of screen
            for (int x=t1.y_index; x>=t2.y_index; x--) {
                Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                error += d_error;
                while (error >= 0.5) {
                    Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                    y += dy > 0 ? +1 : -1;
                    error -= 1.0;
                }
            }
        } else if (dx > 0) { // line drawn towards right side of screen
            for (int x=t1.y_index; x<=t2.y_index; x++) {
                Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                error += d_error;
                while (error >= 0.5) {
                    Board.tiles[x][y].setColour(Color.red);
                    y += dy > 0 ? +1 : -1;
                    error -= 1.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Switched x and y values when d_error is greater than 1. The line disappears when the slope is above 1 and below -1.

Comment: I *suspect* that the line `error -= 1.0` should be outside the `while` loops, though I'm not 100% sure. Can you make that change and let me know if that fixes it?

Comment: @templatetypedef That just only drew the line along the x and y axes.

Comment: Guess I was wrong. :-) Thanks for checking, though.

Comment: @templatetypedef no problem :p thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from a quick google-result:

http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/m308-02b/projects/puhalovic/#alldirections

*"With slopes greater than 1 or less than -1, we must take the previous implementation and swap all x and y values to "move" the calculations back into the "First Octant"."*

IOW: The textbook implementation of the bresenham only works for lines with (in your terms) `d_error<=1`. You'll have to implement the swapping mentioned in the link above.

Comment: So when the slope is greater than 1 or less than -1, I just switch the x and y values?

Comment: I'd say, yes, it's just that. The most straightforward implementation would be one large if-else block for the two cases.

Comment: tried that, the line just disappears now when d_error > 1

Comment: @alexanderd5398 Saw your new code with the swapped x/y branch -- looks almost ok to me, but: when setting `Board.tiles[?][?]`, remember that your local `x` now actually represents `y` and vice versa!

Comment: Tried switching those before I updated the question but I guess I didn't realize that there were four `Board.tiles` that needs switching, so I only did two. Switched all of them and now it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!